# Configuring postfix and dovecot for Secure IMAP and SMTP

Tags: postfix, configuration, dovecot

I have a clean install of postfix and dovecot-core dovecot-imapd dovecot-lmtpd installed on Debian 8 OS.

I want to configure mail to work with PAM but I want to restrict it to users who are part of the `usermail` group so not every linux user has mail access.

I'd also like to make sure the following files were configured properly. I want to make sure user/pass is not sent in plain text and that it is encrypted.

I am showing only the lines I have modified. For a section I wasn't sure of, I have asked a question.

***dovecot/10-auth.conf***

```
disable_plaintext_auth = yes
auth_username_chars = abcdefg....AbCdefg...0123...@
```

Should `plain login` be used for Secure SMTP and IMAPS or just `plain`?

```
auth_mechanisms = plain login
```

This if for PAM authentication

```
!include auth-system.conf.ext
```

***dovecot/10-master.conf***

All others are commented out so only IMAPS will work.

```
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
|
```

Is `postfix` the correct user, or should I be using dovecot here?

```
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
  mode = 0600
  user = postfix
  group = postfix
}

service auth {
```

Do I need to use this instead of Postfix smtp-auth?

```
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    #mode =
    #user =
    #group =
  }
```

Should this be using `postfix` or `dovecot` as the user?

```
  # Postfix smtp-auth
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
  mode = 0666
  user=postfix
  group=postfix
}
```

***dovecot/10-mail.conf***

Is it okay to use maildir instead of Maildir? Would email clients or the server have issues using all lowercase?

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
```

***dovecot/10-ssl.conf***

```
ssl = required

ssl_cert = /etc/dovecot/*.pem
ssl_key = /etc/dovecot/private/*.pem
```

Do I need to exclude !SSLv2 and !SSLv3 to force TLS?

Here is the output of dovecot -n:

```
 mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
 namespace inbox {
   inbox = yes
   location =
   prefix =
 }
 passdb {
   driver = pam
 }
 protocols = imap lmtp
 service auth {
   unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
     group = postfix
     user = postfix
     mode = 0666
   }
 }
 service imap-login {
   inet_listener imaps {
     port = 993
     ssl = yes
   }
 }
 service lmtp {
   unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
     group = postfix
     user = postfix
     mode = 0600
   }
 }
 ssl = required
 userdb {
   driver = passwd
 }
```

***postfix/main.cf***

```
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
```

***postfix/master.cf***

I just uncommented this line:

```
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

UPDATE:

With this config I'm getting an error message when trying to send mail from client to a gmail acount. My iPhone also gets an authentication error message. The user has been created and using the password entered.

```
Warning: hostname mobile.a.b.c.d-mycingular.net does not resolve to address a.b.c.d
connect from unknown
warning: SASL: connect to private/auth failed: no such file or directory
fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
/usr/lib/postfix/smtpd bad command startup --throttling
```

Answer (score 2):

**dovecot/10-auth.conf**

You should set both PLAIN and LOGIN, your actual configuration looks good.

**dovecot/10-master.conf**

That's not necessary to comment the other services, with

```
ssl = required
```

In your dovecot configuration, users will only be able to login if they are connected through ssl. That's a better approach since users may want to use [STARTTLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STARTTLS).

For the authentification socket, you should use the user that is running the 3rd party service, in this case you should set postfix as user.

**dovecot/10-mail.conf**

You can set maildir without uppercases without any issues here.

**dovecot/10-ssl.conf**

You will not force tls by disabling SSLv2 and SSLv3 but you are going to prevent users from using SSL.

**postfix/main.cf**

This part looks good.

```
warning: SASL: connect to private/auth failed: no such file or directory
```

is meaning that the dovecot authentification cannot be found. You should ensure the authentification socket file is present in this directory

Comment: Awesome. I modified all the files you mentioned. I still can't get private/auth working though. Do I just create the file myself? Or is this something generated by starting the service?

Comment: It should be created at the service start but maybe there is not enough permissions on the parent folder? Is the file exists when you starts the service?

Comment: /var, /var/spool, /var/spool/postfix,  have drwxr-xr-x root:root

Comment: Removed all packages and did a re-install. I now have SMTP with SSL working but the connection to IMAP gets refused.